# Using Facebook-Twitter login buttons with HTTP

Tags: php, facebook, http, twitter, https

I am new in web developing and I am developing a website now. I want to use login systems with social networks like facebook and twitter. They are both working with HTTPS and I am wondering if it is okey to use these login systems on my HTTP website? Or it will be better not to use them? Any opinions from you will guide me to decide.

Update:Time is not the problem. I am asking that because of security.For example; are they using cookies to keep users logged in? According to my researh using cookies is dangerous with HTTP. Or am I totally wrong about the way I thinking?

Answer (score 0):

It is not as easy as you might think to integrate Social Logins into your site. They use standards like [OAuth](http://oauth.net/2/). The best point to start to get hands on with one of the social login APIs like the [facebook login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/).

So if i look at how you asked your question, i would say for you it would be better not to use them. You can try, but it will take quite some time to get them to work.

Comment: Time is not the problem, I am asking that because of security.For example; are they using cookies to keep users logged in? According to my researh using cookies is dangerous with HTTP. Or am I totally wrong about the way I thinking?